# React get previous state

Tags: reactjs, state

I am using a date picker plugin and it is a little cranky.  There is one case where I would like to access previous state, and set current state to it.  Is there an easy way to do this, or do I have to create a previous state property in the component and update it every time I setState?  thanks

Comment: It will be better if you can show an example code or main code.

Answer (score 1):

Use `componentDidUpdate` to get access to previous `state` and previous `props`

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState,snapshot){}
```

Answer (score 1):

It'll be more helpful if you'll provide a code. Considering your problem statement here is a possible solution:

```
this.setState((prevState) => ({payload: prevState.payload.concat(data)}));
```

1) `payload` is a state of a component

2) `data` is updated value